# How do i pass my scope correctly to look for variables

Tags: javascript

i was trying to use the javascript APPLY function to pass scope from 1 function to another, but it seems that i might be doing it wrong?

Here is a fiddle if you need it:  **http://jsfiddle.net/C8APz/**

Here is my code:

```
function a(){
    var x = "hello";
    b.apply(this, []);
}

 function b(){
    console.log("x: ", x);
}

a();
```

i was thinking that while the scope is passed, the variables / variable reference are not.

Is there a way to do something like this without defining Globals?

Should i add the data to the actual part of it, such as `this.x = x;`?  and then in the other function just fetch it?  `var x = this.x;`

```
function a(){
    var x = "hello";
    this.x = x;
    b.apply(this, []);
}

 function b(){
    var x = this.x;
    console.log("x: ", x);
}

a();
```

**Edit:**  It seems that the second example assigns in the global scope, which isnt good, and with the scope, i was attempting to pass an understanding of context to.  It seems that you really have to define a context before you pass it, otherwise, for the most part *this* refers to `window`

Comment: That isn't what `apply` does. You cannot pass a scope from one function to another.

Comment: The scope cannot be passed like this, however the scope can flow if you define b within a, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C8APz/1/).

Comment: the second code segment does in fact work, so i assumed that you can infact pass scopes if things are properly defined inside of `this` though im not sure if it is good form to do so.  I usually use `$.apply` when extending functions in OOP design

Comment: @Fallenreaper — Don't confuse scope and context.

Comment: ooh!  Yea, that mightve been my issue.  :)  I was thinking scope was the lifecycle of a function and all the variables defined therein.  Thats why I was thinking i could write an extension in which would do this.

Comment: @Quentin I guess, i should write up a new question about passing context around, or will i end up arriving at the same answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass scope around.

You can either move the function declaration for `b` inside the function declaration for `a` so that the scope is right to start with, or you can pass the variables you care about using arguments.

---

```
function a(){
    var x = "hello";
    b();

    function b(){
        console.log("x: ", x);
    }
}

a();
```

---

```
function a(){
    var x = "hello";
    b(x);
}

function b(x){
    console.log("x: ", x);
}

a();
```

Comment: I did notice that i can do something like my second code sample.  Is that bad form?

Comment: In strict mode, you are trying to set a property on `undefined` which will throw an exception. In non-strict mode, you are setting a property on the default object (`window` in a browser), which is a global and thus has all the usual warnings about globals associated with it.

Comment: I just noticed the edit.  Yea, i didnt want to change the passed in args as those are for other variables.  I was trying to create a custom flag which is in a rare case, in which i dont add additional parameters.

Comment: oh.  Ok.  Yea, i was thinking that given the scope of the function lasts until it finished executing, that i could extend the function with my intended goals.  Maybe im thinking moreso of different languages.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `var x;` out of the function body...

```
var x;
function a(){
    x = "hello";
    b.apply(this, []);
}

function b(){
    //a.apply(this,[]);
    console.log("x: ", x);
}

a();
```

Comment: Question had:  **Is there a way to do something like this without defining Globals?**

Comment: yea, i wasnt trying to do it that way.  it is why i am trying to pass scope/context around such that variables would be assigned without changing the underlying code segments.  That way:  x is already assigned, and in the child function, i could just say things like:   `if(typeof x != 'undefined') console.log("x:", x);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407048/accessing-variables-from-other-functions-without-using-global-variables

Comment: Yea, my second attempt was trying to make it a property of this, though it just essentially made it a global in the process. >_>