# Access variable in one method which was used in other method

Tags: javascript, salesforce-lightning

I Want to access variable from doinit to saveexpenses method. I am trying to access temp variable in saveExpense. The console is throwing undefined

```
 ({
 doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.getMatrix(component, event);
    helper.getRolesConverted(component, event);
    var temp=0;
},
saveExpenses: function(component, event, helper) {
     helper.saveExpenses(component, event);
     console.log('temp value ',temp);
},
});
```

Comment: ...And? Have you tried accessing it, maybe passing it to a function call?

Comment: it is throwing as undefined

Comment: Which variable are you trying to access? Please update your question to indicate what you have tried, the expected behaviour and the actual error behaviour (this will help us have better context to answer the question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing variables from other functions without using global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407048/accessing-variables-from-other-functions-without-using-global-variables)

Comment: make it a global variable for the file? pass it as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp;
({
 doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.getMatrix(component, event);
    helper.getRolesConverted(component, event);
    temp=0;
},
saveExpenses: function(component, event, helper) {
     helper.saveExpenses(component, event);
     console.log('temp value ',temp);
},
});
```